# DynamoDB client in local with UI like PHPMyAdmin

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, local-database

I am creating web service in zend framework which uses DynamoDB. So I installed DynamoDB in local. But it's not easy to use. Even for inserting data and update any data for testing for purpose I have to write a script.

Is there any DynamoDB client available for MAC ? In which we can insert/update/delete data from UI.

**EDIT**

**Doubts**

1)  Do I have to run a SQL to see table data?  I thought there would be GUI for this.

2) I am not able to use where clause in SQL. What if I want to see one or two records from all? Is there a way to use conditions in this?

3) All fields of a row is not visible and I am not able to scroll it horizontally ?

Comment: have you considered working with the actual DynamoDB? It has free tier usage so you shouldn't pay for playing with it.

Comment: Yes I know that 100 MB is free. Yes we are working with the actual DynamoDB. It's just we want to use local data for now. there are more people than just me so it would be better if we can use DynamoDB in local with some kind of UI. Let me know if you have any tool in mind that supports this.

Comment: Responded in answer to your latest Edit as best as I can. Quick answer: 1 - Yes there is, or you can use the tabs. 2 - You can, see example in Answer edit.  3 - See screenshot.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

YES! I've finally found a solution after struggling with this myself:

1. Run your local dynamodb jar with the following command `java -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -dbPath .`     [this will create a file in whatever directory the Dynamo jar is located in].
2. Download [SQLite Database Browser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/) and extract/install it.
3. Start SQLite Database Browser
4. Navigate to "Open Database" from the file menu
   [image: Open Database]
5. Navigate to the directory from [1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/). Select the file [in this case, ****_us-east-1]
   [image: Open database]
6. You should then see the database contents!!
   [image: Database Contents]

Hope this helps - it's been frustrating me no end!

**!! EDIT !! - in response to original question edit.**

> Doubts
>
> 1) Do I have to run a SQL to see table data? I thought there would be
>   GUI for this.
>
> 2) I am not able to use where clause in SQL. What if I want to see one
>   or two records from all? Is there a way to use conditions in this?
>
> 3) All fields of a row is not visible and I am not able to scroll it
>   horizontally ?

1. Yes - you can do a simple "select" statement, for instance in my examples: "SELECT * FROM tweet_item" returns me the following screenshot:[image: screenshot]
2. Seemingly inadvertanyl - whilst I couldn't get the direct SELECT * FROM XX WHERE XX to work, the like statement does.  For instance `SELECT * FROM tweet_item where tweet_item.hashKey like "%425665354447462400%"` returns me the tweet with tweet_id [my hashKey] of 425665354447462400: [image]
3. Strange - I seem to be able to scroll quite happily [although it is Windows not Mac]. It also automatically tries to re-size the outer frame, too.
   [image]

Comment: I know you said "Mac" and fear not - the SQLite Browser says it supports Mac as well - don't get put off by my Windows demonstration!

Comment: Thanks. It works. But I am still having some doubts in this. I edited my question Please have a look at it.

Comment: Hope they release new version for MAC with horizontal scrolling feature. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You may also try the web version of the tool here https://github.com/webavatar/dynamo-ui

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this problem and found a relatively new solution : https://github.com/aaronshaf/dynamodb-admin

It has provision for GET/POST/PUT/DELETE.

Comment: This is a great solution and is easy to use with Docker via amazon/dynamodb-local

Answer (score 3):

Although its a paid product, which is a bummer, RazorSQL now supports DynamoDB as well, and does let you change the AWS endpoint to point to a local installation.

The mac version (with a free trial) is available here:
http://razorsql.com/download_mac.html

Comment: Required AWS Access and Secret Keys can be set to any string in case of DynamoDbLocal in RazorSQL connection profile.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a very useful ui tool https://github.com/YoyaTeam/dynamodb-manager，It supports almost all data operations。

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For Eclipse users:

Amazon provides **AWS Toolkit for Eclipse IDE**. It can view local and cloud databases. Also if you are using different regions, it has ability to choose from different regions.
You can create attributes, add keys etc..
For installation follow this link: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-eclipse/v1/user-guide/getting-started.html

Answer (score 0):

Dynobase is new DynamoDB GUI Client which also lets you browse and manipulate local DynamoDB instances: https://dynobase.dev/dynamodb-local-admin-gui/

Unfortunately, it's paid but there's free 7-days trial, works on Mac, Windows and Linux: https://dynobase.dev/

Comment: Found a similar tool which supports indexes as well https://github.com/webavatar/dynamo-ui