# Local DynamoDB: How to view contents of a table?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

For listing all tables in a locally-installed instance of DynamoDB, I know that the command is:

`aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000`

Now, I want to view the contents of one of the tables.  What is the command to do that?

Comment: you cant. in dynamodb you need to specify hash key in order to get a result.

Comment: You can check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856530/dynamodb-client-in-local-with-ui-like-phpmyadmin

Answer (score 45):

Go to "http://localhost:8000/shell/" and execute the below script. Please change the table name as per your requirement.

When you run the local DynamoDB the above URL should be up and running.

```
var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({
region: 'us-east-1',
endpoint: "http://localhost:8000"
});
var tableName = "TESTTABLE";

var params = {
TableName: tableName,
Select: "ALL_ATTRIBUTES"
};


function doScan(response) {
if (response.error) ppJson(response.error); // an error occurred
else {
    ppJson(response.data); // successful response

    // More data.  Keep calling scan.
    if ('LastEvaluatedKey' in response.data) {
        response.request.params.ExclusiveStartKey = response.data.LastEvaluatedKey;
        dynamodb.scan(response.request.params)
            .on('complete', doScan)
            .send();
    }
}
}
console.log("Starting a Scan of the table");
dynamodb.scan(params)
.on('complete', doScan)
.send();
```

Comment: When I try to run this code Error is coming like "cannot do operations on a non-existence table" Also I have created the table through code.  From that table, I am able to update, delete the data from my code.

Comment: Just have to change the `tableName` variable in line 5 @bandana.

Comment: how to list tables?

Answer (score 39):

One way of viewing local dynamodb data is to use the command line. You can e.g. do a `scan` of the table. Please note that the `scan`-command can be heavy.

```
aws dynamodb scan \
    --table-name my_table_name \
    --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
```

Skip the `--endpoint-url` parameter if you are using a managed version of DynamoDB.

If you do not wish to do a `scan`, perhaps the `get-item`-command may be suitable.

Commands:

- [scan](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/scan.html)
- [dynamodb](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/index.html)
- [get-item](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/get-item.html)

Comment: The `aws` command referenced in this answer can be downloaded here: https://aws.amazon.com/cli/

Answer (score 11):

A free visualization option for dynamodb local that I came across recently is `dyanamodb-admin`. You can check it out here: https://github.com/aaronshaf/dynamodb-admin

Answer (score 5):

This open-source ([dynamodb-manager](https://github.com/YoyaTeam/dynamodb-manager)) tool is pretty good.

It has the following features:

**Table**

- Add Table
- Edit Table
- Delete Table
- Connect Table
- Add Index(GSI and LSI)
- Delete Index

**Item**

- Add Item
- Edit Item
- Delete Item
- import/export Items

**Search (Table or Index)**

- Scan Table
- Query Table
- Filter Condition

**Usage:**

```
docker pull taydy/dynamodb-manager

docker run -t -p 8080:80 taydy/dynamodb-manager
```

Open the following URL in the browser:

http://localhost:8080/
or
http://127.0.0.1:8080/

Comment: No repo updates in 5 years and docker image doesn't run on Mac ARM.

Answer (score 1):

**RazorSql** does this where dynamo-db can be connected and queried like an sql with dynamo-db limitations.

https://razorsql.com/docs/installation.html

It comes with **30 days** trial license.

**Doc:**https://razorsql.com/docs/dynamodb_sql_support.html#select_scan